# Does gitbook prefer underlines or hyphens in filenames?

Tags: gitbook

Was a frequent Gitbook user a couple years ago, then came back to it. As I recall Gitbook works better with... underlines? separating elements of a filename, as in chapter_01.md

Or does it prefer hypens, as in chapter chapter-01.md? Could not find an answer in documentation.

Comment: Try asking on [WebApps.SE](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), which is for web applications like Gitbook.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question as defined by the [help] guidelines.

Comment: Wait a minute, [ccharvey](http://stackoverflow.com/users/877703/chharvey),  perhaps I thanked you too soon. I'm confused. I see gitbook questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gitbook), not at [WebApps.SE](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/). However, I'm a stackoverflow dilettante and probably missed something.

Answer (score -1):

I did some experimentation and the answer is underline characters are preferred. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction, [ccharvey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/877703/chharvey).